# How to listen to PageView.builder scroll events?

Tags: flutter

I am building a slider with autoPlay intervals.

The timer works great and sets the nextPage

```
      _controller.jumpToPage(
        nextPage
      );
```

My issue is that I want to cancel the timer (and the auto-play) when the user interacts and scrolls manually the PageView.

Listening to the `onPageChanged: (value) {` event will not work as this event is triggered for every animtated page. If I scroll from page 4 -> 0, this will be triggered 3,2,1,0 multiple times.

I want to listen to scroll events and _timer?.cancel()

my code so far:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app/ui/models/autoplay_config.dart';

class TextsSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> texts;
  final AutoplayConfig? autoplay;

  const TextsSlider({Key? key, required this.texts, this.autoplay})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TextsSliderState();
}

class _TextsSliderState extends State<TextsSlider> {
  final _controller = PageController();
  Timer? _timer;
  int? _pageSetByTimer;
  static const _kDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 300);
  static const _kCurve = Curves.ease;
  static const double indicatorHeight = 24;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.autoplay != null) {
      _startTimer(widget.autoplay!);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _stopAutoPlay();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var texts = widget.texts;
    List<Widget> _pages = [];

    final TextStyle style = Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1!;
    double maxTextHeight = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < texts.length; i++) {
      Size size =
          textSize(texts[i], style, MediaQuery.of(context).size.width);
      maxTextHeight = max(maxTextHeight, size.height);
      _pages.add(Text(texts[i], textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: style));
    }

    return SizedBox(
      height: maxTextHeight + indicatorHeight,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: PageView.builder(
              itemCount: _pages.length,
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _controller,
              onPageChanged: (value) {
                print('onPageChanged');
                print('_pageSetByTimer=$_pageSetByTimer, value=$value');
                if (widget.autoplay != null && value != _pageSetByTimer) {
                  _stopAutoPlay();
                }
              },
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return _pages[index % _pages.length];
              },
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: RoundDotsIndicator(
              controller: _controller,
              inactiveColor: AppColors.Grey,
              activeColor: AppColors.Primary,
              itemCount: _pages.length,
              onPageSelected: (int page) {
                _stopAutoPlay();
                _moveToPage(page);
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _moveToPage(int page) async {
    await _controller.animateToPage(
      page,
      duration: _kDuration,
      curve: _kCurve,
    );
  }

  void _startTimer(AutoplayConfig autoplayConfig) {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(
      autoplayConfig.slideDuration,
      (Timer timer) async {
        await _moveToNext(infiniteLoop: autoplayConfig.infiniteLoop);
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _moveToNext({bool infiniteLoop = true}) async {
    final currentPage = (_controller.page ?? 1).toInt();
    int nextPage = -1;
    if (currentPage + 1 < widget.texts.length) {
      nextPage = currentPage + 1;
    } else {
      if (infiniteLoop) {
        nextPage = 0;
      } else {
        // we reached the end slide and have no infiniteLoop config
        _stopAutoPlay();
      }
    }

    if (nextPage != -1) {
      _pageSetByTimer = nextPage;
      _moveToPage(nextPage);
    }
  }

  void _stopAutoPlay() {
    _timer?.cancel();
  }
}
```

and the `autoplay_config.dart`

```
class AutoplayConfig {
  final bool infiniteLoop;
  final Duration slideDuration;

  AutoplayConfig({required this.infiniteLoop, required this.slideDuration});
}
```